# How to get a file from another repository in GITLAB and use as arguement to a python script in current pipleine

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have two projects ProjA and ProjB.

I want to use a yaml file(this is not a gitlab yaml file) from ProjA and pass it to a python script in ProjB's gitlab-ci.yaml file.

Can someone let me know how could we do it ?

Something like:

My ProjectA/common/test.yaml looks like:

test.yaml:

```
test1:
   a: 1
   b: 2
```

Now, I have projectB where I want to run a python script as a part of pipeline which parses the above test.yaml

So, my .gitlab-ci looks like:

```
parse-test:
     python parse_project.py {test.yaml}
```

What would be easiest way to retrieve test.yaml from ProjA and pass it as argument such that my python script could read this file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two solutions : using `git clone` to get all files or the API to retrieve a specific file.

The `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` allow you to clone the repository and use files or to make some API calls. This variable is available in your pipeline because it is a [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

### Git Clone

You can clone the `projectA` during the `projectB` pipeline to get one or more files.

```
parse-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/group/project_a.git
    - cat project_a/common/test.yaml
```

### API

You can use the [Repository Files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository) to get a specific file from `projectA` :

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path
```

Then you have to decode the content and you can save it to a file :

```
parse-test:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add curl jq
  script:
    - test_yaml=$(curl -H "JOB_TOKEN:$CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/repository/files/common%2Etest%2Eyaml?ref=main")
    - content=$(echo $test_yaml | jq .content | base64 -d)
    - echo "$content" >> test.yaml
    - cat test.yaml
```

Comment: How do we generate CI_JOB_TOKEN ? Also, can we download the specific file instead of whole code repo ?

Comment: You can use the api, I made an edit. the variable is available in the pipeline.

Comment: I tried the first approach and get the following error:  unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@/cloudlab.us.oracle.com/cloud-reliability-services/monitoring/common.git/': Could not resolve host: ; Unknown error

Comment: Remove the `/` after the `@` ?

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: How do we generate this path https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/repository/files/common%2Etest%2Eyaml ?

Comment: Check the API doc for this purpose : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository